# Using a comparator in Java

Tags: java, c

I am Having a `tuple <Rank[0] , Rank[1]>` and wanted to sort this in increasing order Rank[0] can be considered as  first digit and Rank[2] as a second digit.

Here is my function:

```
  Arrays.sort(S,new Comparator<Tuples>() {

        public int compare(Tuples a, Tuples b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return (a.Rank[0]==b.Rank[0]) ? ((a.Rank[1]<b.Rank[1]) ? 1:0) :((a.Rank[0]<b.Rank[0])? 1:0);
        }
    });
```

The above thing is not giving be Sorted Array while it's C equivalent works i.e

```
int cmp(struct suffix a, struct suffix b)
{
    return (a.rank[0] == b.rank[0])? (a.rank[1] < b.rank[1] ?1: 0):
               (a.rank[0] < b.rank[0] ?1: 0);
}
```

Why My java Sorting is not working. Please Help

```
static  class Tuples{

          int[] Rank = new int[2];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the parentheses match in both code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
public int compare(Tuples a, Tuples b) {
    int index = a.Rank[0] == b.Rank[0] ? 1: 0;
    return a.Rank[index] - b.Rank[index];
}
```

A little easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)) interface, the compare method must return 1, 0 or -1, that are:

- 0 = the objects are equal
- -1 (or any negative integer) = the
  object a is less than object b
- 1 (or any positive integer) = the
  object a is greater than object b

So your method must be something like below:

```
public int compare(Tuples a, Tuples b) {
    if(a.Rank[0]==b.Rank[0]){ 
        if(a.Rank[1]==b.Rank[1]){ // a == b
            return 0;
        }else if(a.Rank[1]<b.Rank[1]){ // a < b
            return -1;
        }else{ // a > b
            return 1;
        }
    }else{ // a != b
        if(a.Rank[0]<b.Rank[0]){ // a < b
            return -1;
        }else{ //a > b
            return 1;
        }
    } 
}
```

Or in short (and ugly way) it would be like this:

```
public int compare(Tuples a, Tuples b) {
   return (a.Rank[0]==b.Rank[0])?((a.Rank[1]==b.Rank[1])?0:((a.Rank[1]<b.Rank[1])?-1:1)):((a.Rank[0]<b.Rank[0])?-1:1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As SqueezyMo stated in his answer case less and negative integer is missing. One can utilize subtraction to get compact code.

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Tuples>() {
  public int compare(Tuples a, Tuples b) {
    return a.Rank[0] == b.Rank[0] ? a.Rank[1] - b.Rank[1] : a.Rank[0] - b.Rank[0];
  }
});
```

Naturally everything can be done using ternary operators, it drives maintainers crazy.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Tuples a = new Tuples();
  a.Rank = new int[]{1, 2};
  Tuples b = new Tuples();
  b.Rank = new int[]{0, 1};
  Tuples c = new Tuples();
  c.Rank = new int[]{1, 3};
  Tuples[] arr = {a, b, c};
  Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Tuples>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Tuples a, Tuples b) {
      return a.Rank[0] == b.Rank[0]
          ? a.Rank[1] == b.Rank[1]
              ? 0 : a.Rank[1] < b.Rank[1]
                  ? -1 : 1 : a.Rank[0] > b.Rank[0]
              ? 1 : -1;
    }
  });
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i].Rank[0] + ":" + arr[i].Rank[1]);
  }
}
static class Tuples {
  public int[] Rank;
}
```